# memory leak on EditText click

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have an android application which starts with `ItemListActivity` class and in `onCreate()` method I check if user is logged in to app or not (Based on a saved value in sharedPreferences) and if not logged in I change activity to `content_main` activity:

```
if (!SharedPreferencesUtils.sharedPrefHasString(getApplicationContext(),userIDKey,null)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),content_main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

and in `content_main` activity I have simply 2 `EditText`s to get users email and password.

Every thing works fine untill I click on any Edittext, then it starts draining memory and crashes with this log:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 35469582 byte allocation with 16769200 free bytes and 24MB until OOM`.

I'm dealing with this for couple of days and I've read that It occurs when you use edittext in relativeLayout so I changed the layout to LinearLayout and it didn't work either.
My device is Samsung galaxy s5 and android version is 6.0.1

And I keep getting this error when ever I click on any EditText.
And here is my Android profiler memory view:
[image]
Is there any idea what causes this problem?

Comment: I guessed this could be a problem so I removed all images (there is just one for signUp logo and a bacground for edittext). But it makes no change to the result.

Comment: In this line `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),content_main.class);` remove `getApplicationContext()` and instead write `this` and never in the future pass `ApplicationContext()` into intent

Comment: @Devit951
Thanks for your advice.
But I'm afraid it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in Advance Android profiler. You need to disable it as follows:

Go to run/debug configuration -> Profiling -> Uncheck Enable advanced profiling

[image: disable]